# Azure SQL Managed Instance Gives 'target principal name is incorrect' when using DNS alias

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

We have a Azure SQL Managed Instance setup.

All connects okay, using SQL Authentication using SSMS using it's internal hostname (e.g mysvr.database.windows.net).

We have a DNS alias configured, and the dns alias resolves to the same IP address (e.g. mysvr.ourdomain.local resolves to the same IP as mysvr.database.windows.net)

When we try loging in through SSMS or ADS, we get the error :

```
 Cannot connect to mysvr.ourdomain.local.
 
 ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
 
 A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
 error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
 error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) (Microsoft SQL
 Server, Error: -2146893022)
 
 For help, click:
 https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver--2146893022-database-engine-error
 
 ------------------------------
 
 The target principal name is incorrect
```

We have followed the advice [in this post](https://johnsterrett.com/2022/09/20/azure-managed-instance-dns-prefix/) to set this up.

If we set the connection to TRUST SERVER CERTIFICATE = TRUE, the error changes:

```
 Cannot connect to mysvr.ourdomain.local.
 
 ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
 
 Cannot open server "mysvr.ourdomain.local" requested by the login. 
 The login failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40532)
 
 For help, click:
 https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-40532-database-engine-error
```

I have not changed the username or password credentials between connection attempts.

Is there anything else that needs to be configured in order to correctly use an alias for SQL MI?